# Update existing excel file template formulas using ruby

Tags: ruby, excel

I had been using `spreadsheet` to read in a template excel file, modify it and output a new file for the end-user.

As far as I can identify from the documentation spreadsheet provides no way to input or edit formulas in the produced document.

However, the purpose of my script is to read an undefined number of items from a site and enter them into the spreadsheet, then calculate totals and subtotals.

The end user (using excel or libreoffice etc) is then able to make slight modifications to the quantity of items whilst the totals update (due to formulas) as they are accustomed.

I have looked into the `writeexcel` gem which claims to be able to input formulas, but I  can't see how to take an existing template file and modify it to produce my output. I can only create fresh workbooks.

Any tips please? I do not want to use Win32OLE.

Comment: To me, it's not very clear what exactly you're trying to change. Do you just want to include formulas in your new file? Or do you want to provide an interactice (Ruby-based) UI for the end user for editing Excel sheets? And what prevents you from just using `spreadsheet`, like you did in the past?

Comment: I've updated the post, is that clearer? I want to include formulas in the new file and am unable to continue using spreadsheet, because it doesn't support formulas as far as my reading of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is surprisingly difficult; apparently all Gems for handling Excel files are missing some crucial functionality.

I can think of two approaches for this problem:

- use a combination of spreadsheet (to read the Excel file) and use writeexcel (to write the output file)
- use an input file that already contains the required formulas on a separate "formula" sheet and copies the formulas to the "real" sheet

Here's a simplistic version of the second approach:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spreadsheet'

Dir.chdir(File.dirname(__FILE__))

# input file, contains this data
# Sheet0: headers + data (for this simple demo, we will generate the data on-the-fly)
# Sheet1: Formula '=SUM(Worksheet1.A2:A255) in cell A1  
book = Spreadsheet.open 'in.xls'
sheet = book.worksheet 0
formulasheet = book.worksheet 1

# insert some input data (in a real application, 
#   this data would already be present in the input sheet)
rows = rand(20) + 1
(1..rows).each do |i|
  sheet[i,0] = i 
end

# add total at bottom of column C
sheet[rows+1,2] = formulasheet[0,0]

# write output file
book.write 'out.xls'
```

However, this will fail if

- you're using the same column for your input data and your totals (since then, the total will try to include itself in the calculation)